# 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found on mac osx big sur

Tags: php, macos, php-extension

I am trying to install php 7.4 intl extension using the commands:

- /Applications/XAMPP/bin/phpize
- ./configure
- make

then I get the error:

```
./php_intl.h:31:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found
```

Comment: BTW I installed icu4c using: brew install icu4c

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the dev package (it is called "libicu-dev" on normal unixoid systems. Not sure about apple...).

Answer (score 7):

- Firstly make sure installed icu4c via "brew install icu4c".
- Secondly check the icu4c path via "brew list icu4c".
- Then export the library include path to your environment, for example:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/include/
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/lib
```

- Finally you can run "make distclean" and "./configure" again

Comment: Thanks that's resolved the issue

Comment: It helps me also, thanks!