# /php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found

Tags: php, macos, xampp, pecl, intl

I'm trying to install intl on Mac os Ventura 13.0.1 with XAMPP 8.1.12 with pecl with this command:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install intl
```

i cannot use directly pecl because i've also other installed php version.

Obviously i've already installed icu4c with command:

```
brew install icu4c
```

Here's result of brew list icu4c

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/derb
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/genbrk
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/gencfu
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/gencnval
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/gendict
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/genrb
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/icu-config
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/icuexportdata
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/icuinfo
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/makeconv
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/pkgdata
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/bin/uconv
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/include/unicode/ (189 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/libicudata.71.1.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/libicui18n.71.1.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/libicuio.71.1.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/libicutest.71.1.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/libicutu.71.1.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/libicuuc.71.1.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/icu/ (4 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/lib/ (18 other files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/sbin/escapesrc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/sbin/genccode
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/sbin/gencmn
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/sbin/gennorm2
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/sbin/gensprep
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/sbin/icupkg
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/share/icu/ (4 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/share/man/ (15 files)
```

Now once i try to install intl with pecl i got this error:

```
 cc -I. -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootQBIGcB/intl-3.0.0/include -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootQBIGcB/intl-3.0.0/main -I/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/main -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/TSRM -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/Zend -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wno-write-strings -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c -MMD -MF php_intl.dep -MT php_intl.lo  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_intl.o
In file included from /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c:25:
In file included from /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:32:
/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_sort.h:23:76: error: expected ')'
typedef int (*collator_compare_func_t)( zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2 TSRMLS_DC );
                                                                           ^
/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_sort.h:23:39: note: to match this '('
typedef int (*collator_compare_func_t)( zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2 TSRMLS_DC );
                                      ^
In file included from /private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.c:25:
/private/var/tmp/pear/temp/intl/php_intl.h:33:10: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found
#include <unicode/ubrk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Once i start the install intl the script ask me:

> Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :

i simple hint enter and got same error but i've also tried to use:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1/include/unicode/
```

but same error appear

I'm loosing my mind with this problem!!

Comment: Have you exported the library include path? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844482/unicode-ubrk-h-file-not-found-on-mac-osx-big-sur

Comment: If you speak about this:
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/include/
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/69.1/lib 
YEs i confirm that i've try same result once i ran install install intl

Answer (score 3):

After having struggled with this for a long while, I finally got it to work.

XAMPP must be in your path, as invoking its `phpize` command will be needed.

First, issue a `php --version` from a terminal to determine the exact PHP version provided by your XAMPP installation. For me, it is 8.2.4. Download the PHP archive matching this version from the following page : https://www.php.net/releases/index.php (that is, for me, the exact link is https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.2.4.tar.gz)

Now type the following commands:

```
$ cd
$ tar xzf php-8.2.4.tar.gz
$ cd php-8.2.4/ext/intl
$ phpize
$ ./configure --enable-intl --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-config
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The last command copies the newly built `intl.so` file to your XAMPP php extensions folder.

Edit `/Applications/XAMPP/etc/php.ini` and make sure `intl` is enabled:

```
extension=intl.so
```

Restart Apache.

Comment: I am getting the error (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')) because XAMPP seems to be build in x86_64. The problem, how do I solve this. If I follow the steps with "arch -x86_64" command, it also doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it helps me a lot.